# React Native Modal transparent with backgroundColor black opacity 0.5 become darker between scene

Tags: background, modal-dialog, react-native, transparent

> RN 0.57,
>   React router flux 4

I have loader component to display loading message in modal on every scene.
I set the modal `transparent` and for modal content I set the `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'`

This is the component code:

```
<Modal
    transparent
    visible={this.props.visible}
    onRequestClose={() => {
        console.log('modal closed')
    }}
>
    <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
        .....
    </View>
</Modal>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
modalBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
},
```

This is where loader component to display:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Loader
        visible={this.props.global.isLoading}
        animating={this.props.global.isLoading}
    />
    ......
</View>
```

I change the state `dispatch(setIsloading(true))` before HTTP REQ and `dispatch(setIsloading(false))` after it return JSON from server, then it change to new Scene.

**The problem is first visible modal is at correct color and transparent, but on the next scene, the color become darker and darker, it's like the component display multiple times at the next scene and triple after that.**

Any idea What cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As these tasks are async you have to make sure that the modal is dismissed before you move to the next scene, in your case you are moving to next scene before this modal is dismissed and once you are on next scene all the async subscriptions are removed hence your modal is not dismissing.

What I do for loading modals is that I do it by refs

**In my loading component**

```
export default class Loader extends Component{
  hide = () => {
           this.setState=({visible:false})
  }
  show = () => {
    this.setState=({visible:true})
  }
  render(){
     return(
          <Modal isVisible={this.state.visible}>
              ....
          </Modal>
      )
   }
}
```

**where you want to show Loader**

```
import Loader from 'path/to/loader'
<Loader ref={r=>this.loader = r}/>
```

**and in your methods when you want to show loader**

```
this.loader.show()
```

**and hide it by calling**

```
this.loader.hide()
```

Comment: where do you call this.loader.hide() ?

Comment: when async function returns with results or in catch block